# error C2259:cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, c++builder

this is the error message with compiler of visual studio 2010(although it has no problem with compiler of micrsoft visual studio 2003)

```
error C2259: 'user_param::UserParamB2<std::string>' : cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members:
    'bool user_param::UserParamBase::readonly(bool)' : is abstract
    c:\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(128) : see declaration of 'user_param::UserParamBase::readonly'
    'bool user_param::UserParamBase::readonly(void)' : is abstract
    c:\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(127) : see declaration of 'user_param::UserParamBase::readonly'
    'SIZE user_param::UserParamBase::winSize(void)' : is abstract
    c:\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\userparambase.h(129) : see declaration of 'user_param::UserParamBase::winSize'
```

My source code looks like as follows:

```
class UserParamBase : public UserParamName
{
    public:
        virtual bool    readonly() =0;
        virtual bool    readonly(bool bReadonly)=0;
        virtual SIZE    winSize()=0;    
        virtual bool    get()=0;
        virtual void    create(CWnd* pParentWnd,const RECT& rect)=0;
        virtual void    close()=0;  
        virtual void    update()=0;
}

...
template <>
class UserParam< string > : public UserParamB2< string >
{
public:
bool get()
{
    AutoCritSec acsWnd(m_csWnd, true);
    if(m_wnd.combobox && m_wnd.combobox->GetSafeHwnd()) {
        CString text;
        m_wnd.combobox->GetWindowText(text);
        this->assign((LPCSTR) text);
    } else if(m_wnd.wnd && m_wnd.wnd->GetSafeHwnd()) {
        char* psz=NULL;
        string s;
        unsigned uSize = m_wnd.wnd->GetWindowTextLength()+1;
        try {
            psz=new char[uSize];
            m_wnd.wnd->GetWindowText(psz,uSize);
            s.assign(psz);
        }
        catch(...) {
            if(psz) delete [] psz;
            throw;
        }
        if(psz) delete [] psz;
        s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(),s.end(),'\r'),s.end());
        this->assign(s);
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

The error message occurs at the `this->assign(s);` statement.

Comment: It is not possible to instantiate an abstract class. The compiler error message is not wrong. You can't "fix" it.

Comment: Note very helpful given that I can trigger this error by adding an interface to a class...

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to be specific since you did not post any code, only unformatted compiler output. However, it seems that you created a subclass of a class with abstract methods `readonly(bool)`, `winSize(void)` and you did not implement these functions in subclass. Therefore, your subclass remained abstract. Implement these methods.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Please tell me how to ix it. as this code is compiling well with Microsoft visual studio 2003 but not 2010.

Answer (score 4):

You can't instantiate an `abstract` class, and no one can help you to do that.

You can either:

- Implement the `class`, but it will no longer be abstract.
- Derive from the `class`, and have the child implement all abstract methods - it seems that this is what you're trying to do.

An abstract method will look something like:

```
virtual void foo() = 0;
```

In your case, the methods `UserParamBase::readonly(void)` and `UserParamBase::winSize(void)` are abstract in the base class.

You must override them in `UserParamB2` and provide an implementation.

Comment: Greetings !
Thank very much for replying my post!

Comment: But I am not able to figure out the correct codes, could you please help me little bit more. Here I am posting the codes.

Comment: error C2259: 'user_param::UserParamB2' : cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members:

Comment: @user1107855 same issue - you're not overriding all abstract methods.

Comment: I am new to VC++, please give useful suggestion how to get rid of this.  As this code is already compiling with Microsoft Visual studio 2003 but not with Visual studio 2010.

Comment: @user1107855 Please format your code and provide the implementation of UserParamB2.